# How do I handle phone numbers with NextJS Links?

Tags: next.js

I have a Link component that uses Next/Link and I'm passing in a telephone number formatted like this: `tel:+15555555555`

However I get an error:

```js
Invalid href passed to router: tel:+15555555555
```

Are telephone numbers not supported?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Next/Link` is a component for page navigation. There is no good reason to use it with special links such as `tel:` / `mailto:`.
Use regular `a` element

```js
<a href={`tel:${phone}`}>tel</a>
```

Comment: i.e. use a regular `<a href={phone_url}>` instead.